# closest point is equal to whole different places in the tree why?

Tags: python

after returning the closest point of a particular point , the next time when i return the closest point to another point the same closest point as before returns. why is that?

```
class kdnode:
    def __init__(self,point,left,right):
        self.point = point
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class kdTree:
    def __init__(self,points,threshold):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.root = self.make_kdtree(points)
        self.froot = None
        self.isFirst = True

    def make_kdtree(self,points,depth = 0):
        if(len(points) <= self.threshold):
            return kdnode(points,None,None)
        dimension = 2
        axis = depth % dimension
        sp = sorted(points,key = lambda point:point[axis])
        mid = len(points)//2
        return kdnode(sp[mid],self.make_kdtree(sp[:mid],depth+1),self.make_kdtree(sp[mid+1:],depth+1))

    def find_closest(self,point,depth=0):
        if self.isFirst:
            self.froot = self.root.point
            self.isFirst = False
        if(self.root.left) is None and self.root.right is None:
            return self.root.point
        axis = depth%2
        if point[axis] > self.root.point[axis]:
            self.root = self.root.right
        else:
            self.root = self.root.left
        return self.find_closest(point,depth+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

```
def find_closest(self,point,depth=0):
    if self.isFirst:
        self.froot = self.root.point
        self.isFirst = False
```

When `find_closest()` is called, it changes itself. This is definitely not what you want. `find_closest()` should be a read-only operation that doesn't destruct the data structure.

Comment: `self` is the current object. `self.isFirst = False` changes the current object. It won't be the same the next time you call `find_closest()`, because you changed it.